# Regular Expression for a currency in a statement

Tags: expression

I wanted to create a RE for currency like $123.45. It should match $123.4, $123.45  It should not match $123.456 or 123.45 I found solutions for this in this site and one of it was

^[$][0-9]+(.[0-9]{1,2})?$

the pattern as expected matches $123.4 and $123.45. But when I put the currency as part of a statement like...
"The cost of one ticket is $123.45 and the cost of 2 is $246.90" Now the pattern doesnt find any match. 
I think its because of ^ and $ which are start and end of the line characters respectively.

How can I get the result as 2 matches? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove ^  and $ from your RE. This symbols tells that search string should start with $ and end with number? Instead of them use brackets to select a group ().

Comment: Based on your suggestion I modified the pattern to ([$][0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?). And then I wrote the statement "the price of one ticket is $125.251 and 2 tickets is $250.50 dollars". I get 2 matches. I want only one match of $250.50. Can you help me please?

Comment: How to understand that `$125.251` is not the end of one sentence and the beginig of a another.